# Access the Assets folder from the .NET IDE in Universal App Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Is there a way to access a file in the Assets folder when in the IDE? I have some sample data I want to load in my IDE while designing my XAML but I'm getting the following error:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache\f4t6b33l.cd2\cjmd0cp0.wb3\Assets\Data\MyData.txt'.

I call the following code but it only works when I run my app:

```
var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
var installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;

string folder = Path.Combine
(installedLocation.Path, "Assets\\Data\\", "NowNextData.txt");
```

I don't want to use a XAML sample data file as my data is actually an html page and contains to much data which is being parsed at run time:

```
<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/Data/SampleData.xaml}">
```

So I saved the html to a datafile saving me having to request the data everytime, and I'm hoping to make my XAML UI design easier and quicker by accessing this.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to load/access the Assets folder from the IDE. If you want to use Design data, you can use the d:DataContext or you can use the following code to detect if your are running in the designer or not:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2011/09/detecting-design-mode-in-windows-8winrt/

Thanks,

Comment: I'm already using this method to detect if I'm running from in the IDE or not, but I was hoping to access local data. I'll read the article anyway as I may found something useful in it, but as mentioned, I don't want to build XAML data. If that doesn't work, I'll just run the app. Slower but better than having to build the XAML manually.

Comment: You won't be able to access local data in designer: the only way is XAML Design Data.